# How to add files to assets folder in android after unzipping dynamically

Tags: android

i am creating an app where i unzip the files and load it to SD card but instead i wish to load them to the assets folder on the project. How to do this can any one help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write into your Apps Asstes Folder.
Use data/ on SD Card or for small things the SharedPreferences instead.

Comment: i am already loading it to the SD card but is there a way to load it to assets folder, thanks for the reply

Comment: If you just want to read from your Files you can put it in Assets Folder, but for your App the Assets Folder is just Readable. If you want to write in the Files you have to copy them to the SD-Card. - A copy back to Assets is also not possible.